# Representation theory definition confusion

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I understand that the "mathematical" (i.e. not how my physics professor sees it) definition of a representation is simply a homomorphic mapping from the group $G$ to GL$(n, V)$. However, my professor does not use the term representation this way. For example, he defines the **fundamental representation** of SU(2) as

> **The fundamental representation**: we define the 2-dimensional representation as a column vector of 2 complex elements which transforms under the algebra, under usual multiplication. We call this $v_i$ where $i=1,2$. The algebra acts on the representation. Under this action, $$ v_i \rightarrow v_i + iM_{ij}v_j,$$

where $M_{ij}$ is a matrix in the algebra.

**My understanding**:

(1) I assume here that he means "representation space", and not "representation", but I'm not sure if this assumption is exactly right.

(2) By transforming "under the algebra", does he mean "transforms under infinitesimal SU(2) transformations"? If so, is that exactly right? Since would a transformation under the algebra look more like $v_i \rightarrow iM_{ij}v_j$ ?

(3) If (1) is the case, then why on earth would somebody even care about the representation space to begin with? It alone doesn't tell us anything about the group.

**Main Question**:

I am asked to

> Show that the symmetrize combination $v_iw_j + v_jw_i$ is a representation. i.e. the transformation moves the fields into linear combinations within the representation.

**My attempt**

First, I assume that he means representation of SU(2) (?). Anyways, I am able to show that the product transforms like

$$v_iw_j \rightarrow v_iw_j + iw_jM_{ik}v_k + iv_i M_{jk}w_k .$$

Applying this to $v_j w_i$ and adding, I am able to show that

$$v_i w_j + v_j w_i \rightarrow v_iw_j + v_j w_i + iM_{ik}(v_jw_k + w_jv_k)  + iM_{jk}(v_iw_k + w_iv_k). $$

I know that this is also symmetrized, but that is about all I know. I have no idea how this is supposed to tell me whether or not this is a representation (or representation space (?), referring back to (1), (3)). The fact that I don't know where to go with this, leads me to believe that I must have some fundamental misunderstanding in the form of the following question:

*How would I show that $v_i w_j + w_i v_j$ is a representation, given the definition in the first block quote?*

Comment: There are two different 'mathematical' definitions here: a group representation is a homomorphism from a group $G$ to $\mathrm{GL}(V)$, but a Lie algebra representation is a homomorphism from the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ to $\mathrm{End}(V)$ (equipped with the commutator bracket).  In the Lie theory context, the two kinds of representation are closely related, but not the same.  If you're talking about 'infinitesimals', that means elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$, not of the group $SU(2)$.